# Post data from Android App to Backend PHP

Tags: php, android

If i assign a value to a variable and pass it to url, it is working fine.

```
$waybill=508518;
$url = 'http://api.ecomexpress.in/track_me/api/mawbd/?awb='.$waybill.'&order=&username=cs@subhashreeinfotech.com&password=@@@@';
$ch = curl_init();                    // initiate curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the output in     string format
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
```

But what i need is , i have to get the waybill number dynamically from android app.For that i am posting the waybill value to back end php code like below.But its not working

```
$waybill=$_POST['bill'];
$url = 'http://api.ecomexpress.in/track_me/api/mawbd/?awb='.$waybill.'&   order=&username=cs@subhashreeinfotech.com&password=@@@@';

$ch = curl_init();                    // initiate curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the output in     string format
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Error : undefined index bill

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST);` what it says and also try to print `print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Comment: try logging the requests along headers and parameters either in file or db with date time and check what you get when requested. And whats the response from the server when you send data from your device?

Comment: you may not be posting any data because of the wrong request probably the issue will be at client where you are consuming your api. i.e. your device

Comment: I think i knew the real problem now. I just want to know how to store $_POST['bill'] data into a variable.

Comment: Post the android code you are using in making the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue using the following code

```
$waybill=$_POST['srt'];
ob_start();
echo $_POST['srt'];
$my = ob_get_contents();

$url='http://52.66.178.241//track_me/api/mawbd/?
awb='.$my.'&order=&username=subhashree54396&password=su54nbh39tmed';
$ch = curl_init();                    // initiate curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the output in 
string format
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
print_r($output);

curl_close($ch);
```